# How to Troubleshoot composite key violation in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys, composite-key

My Access database (2007) has Four tables; Customer, Supplier, Account, and AccountAgeing

AccountAgeing has a composite key made up of the foreign keys of two of the other tables, plus a date. i.e.;

AsAtDate, SupplierID, AccountNumber

I am importing data from excel via a temporary table, and my parent tables (Customers, Suppliers, Accounts) are importing well.

However importing AccountAgeing from my tempTable continually has a key violation. Of 749 possible imports, 746 violate the key. A query to test was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tempTable.[SupplierID], #31/7/14#, tempTable.[AccountNumber]
       FROM tempTable;
```

This returned 749 records (all of them). If this is the case, how do I have a key violation??

The composite key fields are all indexed, with duplicates OK. There is no data in the destination table
[image: These are the indices on my table (obviously I have simplified the names in my question]
I have date and [Account Number] indexed as these are the fields searches will be on.

Comment: Can you show the "Indexes" screenshot of the AccountAgeing  table. I think you have defined the key as three separate indexes instead of a single composite key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sequence of some troubleshooting steps you can try.

1. Remove the primary key from your target table and populate it. If you can't populate the target table, your problem may not be the key itself, and may become apparent based on error messages you receive.
2. If the target table does populate, try adding your desired composite key to the already populated target table.
3. If you are unable to add the key, re-run your "select distinct" query on the populated target table.
4. If you don't select 749 distinct rows, visually inspect the table contents to see what's going on.

These steps should lead you to some insight. Just a guess - but it sounds possible that you may have a data type mismatch somewhere. In cases like this, Access will sometimes convert data on the fly and insert it without giving an error. But in the process the nature of the data are changed, resulting in a key violation in the target table.

I'm curious to hear what you find. Please post a comment when you figure out what the problem is.

Hope it helps. Good luck with the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Marty!! I attempted to populate manually, which errored because there was no matching record in the Customers table.

I discovered that I had incorrectly assigned AccountAgeing to be the parent of Customers, rather than of Accounts.

The business logic is that an AccountAgeing record will always have an Account, but an AccountAgeing record does not always mention Company Number (the primary key of the Customer table).

The fix was binding part of the Account Ageing composite key to the Accounts composite key.

[image]

I am unsure what will happen when I add an ATBRecord which has an account number but no Company number, but that is another question

Answer (score 0):

Check the Indexed Property in table properties - make sure it is not set at Duplicates OK on any of the composite key fields